# run an external program and take a screenshot of it

Tags: python, windows, screenshot

I want to test my application by running it 100 times and taking screenshots of a working thing. 
That's what I have came up with:

```
import sys, string, os
import time
import wx

directory = 'my path to directory containing the .exe'
file = '"directory and .exe path"'

app = wx.App(False)
screen = wx.ScreenDC()
size = screen.GetSize()   

def runprogram(number,sleep_time):
    bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
    mem = wx.MemoryDC(bitmap)
    newfile = str(number) + "_" + str(sleep_time)
    print newfile
    os.chdir(directory)
    os.system(file)
    time.sleep(sleep_time) #seconds
    print "sleeping done"
    mem.Blit(0, 0, size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
    del mem
    bitmap.SaveFile(newfile, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    print "file saved as "+ newfile
    os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM myprogram.exe")

runprogram(1,5)
```

The problem is, that when os.system() is exetuted, the script halts untill i close myprogram window, and than sleeps and takes a screenshot, and I want those actions to be simultaneous. How can I do that?

Comment: Try using the subprocess module instead as os.system will want to wait for the executable to complete with a return status before returning to your program. http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess (look specifically at popen: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)